# Error on npm run deploy with gh-pages and Create-React-App

Tags: reactjs, npm, github-pages, create-react-app

**UPDATE**

**I tried deploying using cmder instead of powershell and it worked! Now when I initally set everything up I was using cmder so I'm not sure if that is the reason or not... but I have no idea why it breaks under powershell.**

---

Everything was working fine and I was able to build my react-app and deploy it to github and then all of a sudden I started getting errors last week whenever I try to run `npm run deploy`

Here is a snippet of the error I get :

**Powershell**

```
> gh-pages -d build

events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn git ENOENT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1020:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:193:32)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:367:16)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:606:11)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:389:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:504:3
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! app@0.1.0 deploy: `gh-pages -d build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the app@0.1.0 deploy script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Spiderman\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-08-15T00_44_09_227Z-debug.log
```

One thing to note is that node is installed on the D: drive and so are all my react files. But it looks like npm is installed partially on the C: drive.

Anyways here is the full log I've narrowed it down to here:

**Debug Log**

```
1 info lifecycle app@0.1.0~deploy: app@0.1.0
12 verbose lifecycle app@0.1.0~deploy: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
13 verbose lifecycle app@0.1.0~deploy: PATH: C:\Users\Spiderman\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin;D:\Users\Spiderman\Websites\PB\app\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;D:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;D:\Program Files (x86)\Brackets\command;D:\Program Files\Git LFS;D:\Program Files\OpenVPN\bin;D:\Program Files\nodejs\;D:\Python34;D:\Program Files\Heroku\bin;C:\Users\Spiderman\AppData\Local\atom\bin;C:\Users\Spiderman\AppData\Roaming\npm
14 verbose lifecycle app@0.1.0~deploy: CWD: D:\Users\Spiderman\Websites\PB\app
15 silly lifecycle app@0.1.0~deploy: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'gh-pages -d build' ]
16 silly lifecycle app@0.1.0~deploy: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
17 info lifecycle app@0.1.0~deploy: Failed to exec deploy script
18 verbose stack Error: app@0.1.0 deploy: `gh-pages -d build`
18 verbose stack Exit status 1
18 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Spiderman\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\lifecycle.js:289:16)
18 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
18 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:191:7)
18 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Spiderman\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\spawn.js:40:14)
18 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
18 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
18 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:891:16)
18 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
19 verbose pkgid app@0.1.0
20 verbose cwd D:\Users\Spiderman\Websites\PB\app
21 verbose Windows_NT 6.3.9600
22 verbose argv "D:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Spiderman\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "deploy"
23 verbose node v6.11.2
24 verbose npm  v5.1.0
25 error code ELIFECYCLE
26 error errno 1
27 error app@0.1.0 deploy: `gh-pages -d build`
27 error Exit status 1
28 error Failed at the app@0.1.0 deploy script
```

https://pastebin.com/gYr9PKtj
PS I am on windows running power shell.

**Package.json**

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": "https://hidden.github.io/hideen/",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase": "^4.1.3",
    "gh-pages": "^1.0.0",
    "re-base": "^3.0.2",
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1",
    "react-router": "^4.1.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.1.1",
    "react-scripts": "1.0.10",
    "react-transition-group": "^1.2.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build"
  }
}
```

Comment: I had the exact opposite problem, I was using command prompt, and it stopped working. I went into powershell and it worked! Super strange. I have no idea why gh-pages would only work under one and not the other.

Comment: Any chance you're project files are on a different drive than your C: drive? 

I think that may have been my problem. cmder was installed on C: but my project files were on D:

Comment: no, both were on the C drive. I did take this repo as a mirror from another repo, so that may be the problem, but it doesn't explain why cmd would not work and powershell works. I do most of my work in cmd, so that may be why, but it still doesn't make sense.